# Access Wamp 3.1 from PC in local network

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp, wampserver

I know there have been a lot of questions regarding this topic, but I still was not able to get it to work.

I've set up a Wordpress site and a virtual host for that site locally on my notebook (via Wamp 3.1) and now I want to access it from another PC on the same network. On the localhost everything works fine.

My `httpd-vhosts.conf` file looks like this:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#

#Wamp
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
 Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#Hp1
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hp1.local
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp64/www/hp1"
    <Directory  "d:/wamp64/www/hp1">
Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.100.76
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've added `192.168.100.88 hp1.local` (the ip of notebook) to my PC's host file. 192.168.100.76 is the ip of my PC.

I can ping my PC from my notebook and vice versa.

I've tried to access the site via

```
http://192.168.100.88
and 
http://hp1.local
```

But to no avail. Not even a 403 or anything, just

> Error: network timeout

**Edit:**
Thinks I've tried:

- Put an inbound rule for port 80 in place (on my PC)
- Deactivated the firewall (on my PC)
- Added Apaches httpd.exe to my hosts firewall exceptions (solution)

Comment: You need the inbound rule on the notebook. The one running WAMPServer

Comment: Also add `192.168.100.88 hp1.local` to the host file of the client PC (the one that does not have WAMPServer running on it

Comment: `192.168.100.88 hp1.local` was in my PC's host file already. But I've added the inbound rule to the host now, too, even though it was already working. Just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Firewall is likely blocking incoming connections from Apache. Add an exception for Wamp's incoming traffic (or just turn it off, but doing so would be bad for security).

Comment: I've added an inbound rule for Port 80, but that did not help. Then I just deactivated the firewall, but that didn't help either.

Comment: Ah, now it works, had to add Apaches httpd.exe to my hosts firewall exceptions. But maybe that's what you meant all along. Thank you very much!